# Why does my Postgres users have execute permission on a table?

Tags: postgresql

I log in as a `PostgreSQL` superuser using `psql`, and issue a `\dp`, and the output contains the following line:

`public | account                    | table    | someuser=arwdx/someuser`+|

If I understand correctly this means that `someuser` has execute permission on the `account` table? But what does that mean? How can I revoke that execute permission?

Note, all the tables in this database have execute permissions on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking that `x` represents the `trigger` privilege which is the right to attach triggers to a table and was probably created by the default table privileges given to the owner of the table.

You can read all the fine detail here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-grant.html

If you are wanting to put more granular permissions on a table it's usually best to do something like `REVOKE ALL ON table FROM role;` followed by explicitly granting those privileges you want the role to have.